# Selenium Safari browser Timeout Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have a webElement using Xpath for inputText and trying to write it on from my script. I ran my script for various browsers to validate the inputText, however, except for Safari, all other browsers work fine, perhaps, in Safari, I am getting a Timeout exception. Does anyone face this issue in safari?

Comment: check if element is indeed present in safaroi

Comment: yes, it is present in safari. This issue is kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout exception occurs when element is not captured in particular interval,So you can check waiting time for an element if it is defined globally in your code and also increase timing of wait for locate an element from the script.